# CSS/Jquery Fade in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Just wondering what the best way to approach this. I have a nav menu that is white. When the page scrolls down it becomes sticky. When it becomes sticky I want the background color to fade from white to (let's say) blue.

I'm using the Jquery plugin "Waypoints" and thought I could use a toggle to do this, but can't figure it out as I only want to fade the background not the entire div (as that would cause the menu titles to also fade)

Any ideas?

Here is the JS

```
$('#megaMenu-sticky-wrapper #megaMenu.ubermenu-sticky').waypoint(function() {
   $('#megaMenu-sticky-wrapper #megaMenu.ubermenu-sticky').toggleClass( 'animate' );
```

----What this JS does is when #megaMenu-sticky-wrapper #megaMenu.ubermenu-sticky reaches the top of the screen (becomes "sticky") it will toggle the class .animate (this is where the css will go for the blue background, and any animation stuff)

I've previously used this to animate with keyframes. Ex. specify the keyframes and then in the class .animate I would include the keyframe animation so that it would animate whenver I would get to a certain part of the page.

Let me know if any more info is needed.

Just looking for some guidance or direction into how I can target just the background for the fade in

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to set the background as an `rgba()` value, where the "a" is for the `alpha`, or opacity.

```
.animate {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
}
```

This isn't supported by IE8, though.

**EDIT:** For the fade effect, add the following CSS (here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZyLx/)):

```
#megaMenu-sticky-wrapper #megaMenu.ubermenu-sticky {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: but how would I animate the fade in?

Comment: I edited my answer with some information that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163427/trying-to-fade-navigation-background-only-not-links/). I copied my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163427/trying-to-fade-navigation-background-only-not-links/38163895#38163895) from that post over.

Use the transition property. Basically you set the transition property to the background color of the navigation class and give it a duration.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('.navigation').css('background-color', 'blue');
        } else {
            $('.navigation').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        });
```

```css
 .navigation{
  height:1000px; 
  background-color: black;
  transition:background-color 2s;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<nav class="navigation" id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#top" id="tp_link" class="active">Top</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item2" id="f_link">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item3" id="s_link">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item4" id="c_link">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bottom" id="sm_link">Botton</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: We try to close duplicate questions on Stack Overflow. If the questions are similar enough that your answer applies to both then one of the questions should be closed as a duplicate.