# Trying to fade Navigation background only not links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I am trying to fade in the navigation background only with jquery but when doing so, It somehow also makes the navigation links to fade out with the navigation background.

Here is my code:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {

            $('.navigation').fadeIn(500).css('background-color', '#787878');

        } else {

            $('.navigation').fadeOut(500).not("ul li a");

        }
```

**Here is the Navigation**

```
`nav class="navigation" id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#top" id="tp_link" class="active">Top</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item2" id="f_link">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item3" id="s_link">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item4" id="c_link">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bottom" id="sm_link">Botton</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>`
```

I have tried using the `not()` function to omit only the links so that when the user scrolls back up, the only thing that remains is the links itself that go with a background image. The only thing that should disappear is the background color behind it.

Any suggestions with jQuery would help. I am pretty new with it

Comment: Is `.navigation` a `<div>` containing the links?

Comment: actually it is more like `<nav class="navigation"`>

Comment: And the links are within the `<nav>` element?

Comment: I added the navigation module using HTML

Comment: So calling `$('.navigation').fade()` is going to apply to the whole `.navigation` element including all child elements (i.e. the links).

Comment: If you want a fade effect just on the background, you'll need to look into animations

Comment: Here's an article that might help https://www.sitepoint.com/scroll-based-animations-jquery-css3/

Answer (score 0):

Use the transition property. Basically you set the transition property to the background color of the navigation class and give it a duration.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {

            $('.navigation').css('background-color', 'blue');

        } else {

            $('.navigation').css('background-color', 'red');

        }
        });
```

```css
 .navigation{
  height:1000px; 
  background-color: black;
  transition:background-color 2s;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<nav class="navigation" id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#top" id="tp_link" class="active">Top</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item2" id="f_link">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item3" id="s_link">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item4" id="c_link">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bottom" id="sm_link">Botton</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I roughly write a code for you. Here is the example how you can change only background color using jquery.

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function myfunction() {
        $("#nav").css("-webkit-transition", "all 0.6s ease")
        .css("backgroundColor", "grey")
        .css("-moz-transition", "all 0.6s ease")
        .css("-o-transition", "all 0.6s ease")
        .css("-ms-transition", "all 0.6s ease");
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navigation" id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#top" id="tp_link" class="active">Top</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item2" id="f_link">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item3" id="s_link">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item4" id="c_link">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bottom" id="sm_link">Botton</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Does this work similar to this post? https://redvinestudio.com/demos/how-to-make-your-navigation-appear-on-scroll-with-jquery/

Comment: I am trying to keep the links visible although the parent container would simply become translucent or invisible when reached atop since scrolling down, mainly my site consist of white background and the links get lost

Comment: @harreola Simply put above js code into ur scrolling function and customize according to your need. This piece of code does't effect your navigation links to fade out with the navigation background.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out as soon as I get back home :)